# Linkedin Login Error in Signed APK(Android)

Tags: android, authentication, linkedin-api, malformed

I use LinkedIn Login in android with the following code

```
private void linkedInLogin() {
    /*isLogin();*/
    System.out.println( "insidelogin" + "linkedin" );
    LISessionManager.getInstance( getApplicationContext() ).init( this, buildScope(), new AuthListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthSuccess() {
            System.out.println( "sucesslogin" + "linkedin" );
            accessLinkedInData();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
            // Handle authentication errors
            System.out.println( "login_error" + error );
        }
    }, true );
}

private void accessLinkedInData() {
    String url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url)?format=json";
    //String url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json";
    APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance( getApplicationContext() );
    apiHelper.getRequest( this, url, new ApiListener() {
        @Override
        public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse apiResponse) {
            //System.out.println( "apiResponse" + apiResponse.getResponseDataAsString() );
            JSONObject linkedinResponse = apiResponse.getResponseDataAsJson();
            firstName = linkedinResponse.optString( "firstName" );
            lastName = linkedinResponse.optString( "lastName" );
            emailAddress = linkedinResponse.optString( "emailAddress" );
            mLinkedInID = linkedinResponse.optString( "id" );
            if (linkedinResponse.has( "pictureUrl" )) {
                profilePicUrl = linkedinResponse.optString( "pictureUrl" );// profile picture for uploading sometimes it get null
            }else {
                profilePicUrl = "";
            }
            isSocialLogin = true;
            socialLogin();
        }

        @Override
        public void onApiError(LIApiError liApiError) {
            // Error making GET request!
        }
    } );
}

private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build( Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS );
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Add this line to your existing onActivityResult() method
    LISessionManager.getInstance( getApplicationContext() ).onActivityResult( this, requestCode, resultCode, data );
}
```

and generate a hash key using this code in a development mode

```
private void computeHash() {
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo( "com.cap.connectingjobs", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES );
        for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance( "SHA" );
            messageDigest.update( signature.toByteArray() );
            Log.d( "KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString( messageDigest.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT ) );
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After all, this works fine but when I create hash key for final release using

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

and added the hash key to the LinkedIn developer account and run the release apk file it shows an error

```
"errorMessage": "either bundle id or package name \/ hash are invalid, unknown, malformed", "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ERROR"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since only signed APKs have this problem, you have configured an incorrect release key hash value.

Try checking the release key hash value of the keystore correctly listed in the "android package name and hash" LinkedIn application configuration correctly listed in your [LinkedIn application's configuration:](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.co.in&sl=zh-CN&sp=nmt4&u=https://www.linkedin.com/start/join%3Fsession_redirect%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.linkedin.com%252Fdeveloper%252Fapps%26trk%3Dlogin_reg_redirect&xid=17259,1500004,15700021,15700043,15700124,15700149,15700168,15700186,15700190,15700201,15700208&usg=ALkJrhicbVmoNfJQ3wdNIS0m08wn0j6_xg)

**Generate a release key hash**

To generate a release key hash, use the following command:

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

**Configuration value**

You can provide one or more values ​​in the configuration of your LinkedIn application using the following comma-separated format:

```
Android.Package.Name,Key-Hash-Value
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You... the issue is in generating release key hash. 1) create a signedApk 2) Create a Hash Key 3) add the hash key to the LinkedIn

Answer (score 0):

Go to Play store and dowload the **MODIFIED** version of the apk (Your App -> Versions -> Manage -> Download symbol near apk icon).

Follow the instructions here: https://ibby.ca/extract-key-hash-apk-file/. Generate another key hash, convert the SHA1 into Base64 value in http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php and register it in Linkedin as your release hash.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! While this may answer the question, link-only answers can become invalid if the resource goes away. It might be best to copy some of the instructions over to this answer, to make sure future users benefit equally much from your work.