# LinkedIn Signed Apk Issue in Android

Tags: android, authentication, linkedin-api, social-networking

I completed the code of LinkedIn login and generated a hash key with signed apk and added the hash key to the LinkedIn developer account and installed the signed APK on my phone, and it works fine. After all, when I upload in to play store and download the app it again shows this error.

```
"errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST",
"errorMessage": "either bundle id or package name \/ hash are invalid, unknown, malformed"
```

I'm not copying-pasting my entire code here because my code has no difference from this link

[Linkedin Login Error in Signed APK(Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203475/linkedin-login-error-in-signed-apkandroid)

```
 I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=com.linkedin.android.auth.AUTHORIZE_APP 
 cat=[com.linkedin.android.auth.thirdparty.authorize] 
 cmp=com.linkedin.android/.liauthlib.thirdparty.LiThirdPartyAuthorizeActivity 
(has extras)} from uid 11044 on display 0
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class 
com.linkedin.android.messaging.realtime.RealTimeConnectionChangedEvent
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class 
org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
W/Binder_F: type=1400 audit(0.0:1418): avc: denied { ioctl } for 
path="socket:[116828]" dev="sockfs" ino=116828 ioctlcmd=7704 
scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 
tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class 
com.linkedin.android.infra.events.NetworkConnectionChangedEvent
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class 
org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
W/Binder_F: type=1400 audit(0.0:1419): avc: denied { ioctl } for 
path="socket:[116828]" dev="sockfs" ino=116828 ioctlcmd=7704 
scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 
tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
W/Binder_C: type=1400 audit(0.0:1420): avc: denied { ioctl } for 
path="socket:[94116]" dev="sockfs" ino=94116 ioctlcmd=7704 
scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 
tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
W/Binder_C: type=1400 audit(0.0:1421): avc: denied { ioctl } for 
path="socket:[94116]" dev="sockfs" ino=94116 ioctlcmd=7704 
scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 
tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
I/ActivityManager: Displayed 
com.linkedin.android/.liauthlib.thirdparty.LiThirdPartyAuthorizeActivity: 
+298ms
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class 
com.linkedin.android.messaging.realtime.RealTimeConnectionChangedEvent
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class 
org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
I/System.out: login_error{
/System.out:   "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST",
I/System.out:   "errorMessage": "either bundle id or package name \/ hash are 
invalid, unknown, malformed"
I/System.out: }
W/Binder_D: type=1400 audit(0.0:1422): avc: denied { ioctl } for 
path="socket:[112610]" dev="sockfs" ino=112610 ioctlcmd=7704 
scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 
tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
W/Binder_D: type=1400 audit(0.0:1423): avc: denied { ioctl } for 
path="socket:[112610]" dev="sockfs" ino=112610 ioctlcmd=7704 
scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 
tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class 
com.linkedin.android.messaging.realtime.RealTimeConnectionChangedEvent
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class 
org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class 
com.linkedin.android.messaging.realtime.RealTimeConnectionChangedEvent
D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class 
org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
```

Comment: ca you mention logcats here

Comment: logcats added on the question